# How to forward request logs to console in Symfony? Now logs are saved to a file

Tags: symfony, logging

I run the server in cmd with this command in Symfony. And it says that the server is running:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\vs\ge>php app/console server:run
Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

And that's all. No any log info is sent to console when I make page reloads. All logs are saved to a file. But I want to forward logs to console, like it is done in Node.js for example. How to set it in Symfony2?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, when you run this command (which is not really recommanded by the way, as it is not as powerful as a server running with Apache or Nginx for example), when you execute your script (going on `http://localhost` for example), it is not aware that it is running on a php server.

But, I guess that if you really want some logs, maybe you should extend the symfony command and add some logs there ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find a nice solution:

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-show-logs-in-console